# How to implement side menu in android which can call different activity on clicking the menu item

Tags: android

I was in a search for implementing a facebook like side menu in my application. I got many samples after a deep search. But it is not matching my need. I need a side menu with items and on clicking each items a separate activity need to called and from there also i need to have this side menu access.

Any Help will be deeply Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check out SlidingMenu, it does what you want: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Android slide out menu similar to Facebook Android App](https://github.com/akotoe/android-slide-out-menu) same like faceboook Side Menu.

I hope it will help you out.